# Time Complexity Analysis Of while loop

Tags: algorithm, while-loop, big-o, computer-science, data-analysis

```
int y=1;                                                                                       
int j=0;                                                                                        
while(j<=2n){                                                                            
   y=y+i;                                                                                        
   j=j+2;                                                                                        
}
```

How many times the loop header while(j<=2n) will be checked in this case if j was increased by +1 I know that the loop will be checked 2n+1 times. So I am quite confused in this case as j is increasing by + 2 every time it is going through half iteration than when j was increased by +1

Comment: What is `n` in `while(j<=2n)` and `i` in `y=y+i`?

Comment: n depends on the input provided by the user

Answer (score 1):

The j increased by 2 in each iteration, which means that it will take *half* of the time compared to increasing by 1 in each iteration.

Which means the Time Complexity here is 2n/2 = n.

So O(n).

Answer (score 0):

As it is increased by `2` in each iteration, the number of loop iteration will be `2n/2 = n` times.

Comment: So the loop header will be checked n+1 times right? Because it has to check 1 more time to be false.

Comment: @Buddy Right, but it does not matter in terms of asymptotic complexity analysis.